# Reference request: Étale base change of differential-graded algebras

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products, differential-graded-algebras

I've asked this question on [Math.StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268724/reference-request-%c3%89tale-base-change-of-differential-graded-algebras), but didn't receive an answer, so I'd like to try my luck here.

---

I'm looking for a reference for the following fact, which I've recently stumbled upon:

**Lemma.** Let $A^*$ be a CDGA (graded-commutative differential-graded algebra). We assume that $A^*$ is concentrated in nonnegative cohomological degrees. Let furthermore $A^0\rightarrow B^0$ be an étale ring morphism. Then the graded-commutative ring $B^0\otimes_{A^0}A^*$ can be equipped with a natural CDGA-structure, which satisfies the following universal property: If $E^*$ is a CDGA equipped with a $B^0$-algebra structure on $E^0$, then every CDGA-morphism $A^*\rightarrow E^*$ extends uniquely to a CDGA-morphism $B^0\otimes_{A^0}A^*\rightarrow E^*$.

For example, to construct the differential $d^1\colon B^0\rightarrow B^0\otimes_{A^0}A^1$, we need to specify a $B^0$-module map $\Omega_{B^0/\mathbb Z}\rightarrow B^0\otimes_{A^0}A^1$. But $\Omega_{B^0/\mathbb Z}\cong B^0\otimes_{A^0}\Omega_{A^0/\mathbb Z}$ since $A^0\rightarrow B^0$ is étale, so we can just take the $A^0$-module map $\Omega_{A^0/\mathbb Z}\rightarrow A^1$ characterising the differential on $A^*$ and tensor it with $B^0$.

I've convinced myself that this lemma is true (but please tell me if you think it is not), and if so, I would be surprised if it hasn't been done before, since it seems like a natural question. However, all I could find in the literature are treatments of  tensor products of the form $B^*\otimes_RA^*$, where the differentials of $B^*$ and $A^*$ are $R$-linear.